# Create Volatile Table in Teradata Using ODBC in SAS

Tags: sql, sas, odbc, teradata

I am trying to create volatile table in Teradata using ODBC in SAS as I do not have SAS license to access the Teradata engine.

Below is the Teradata SQL query I am using in SAS:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE base_acct_extract
(
account_id varchar(30)
)
PRIMARY INDEX(account_id)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;


INSERT INTO base_acct_extract VALUES ('ABC1200');
```

*Can I even use the ODBC engine to create a volatile table? If yes, how do I create and access the table? If not, what are the alternative ways?*

Comment: Did you try it, was there an error message? Volatile Tables are SQL, independent of the client connection. But they're dropped when the seesion disconnects, so check how SAS handles the connection

Comment: If using LIBNAME, specify CONNECTION=GLOBAL. If using explicit CONNECT then you can alternatively define an alias to be used in the EXECUTE BY.